# Change DATE Format while uploading data source

Tags: looker-studio

The default date format in google data studio, data source is `YYYYMMDD`. I would like to change the format to `DDMMYYYY` as my excel spreadsheet "DATA" data is in the format of `DDMMYYYY`. I am currently trying to create a new data field by "clicking +Add a field" to customize.

The followin code is not working:

`TODATE(LoadDate,'%d/%m/%y','%d%m%y')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TODATE function is

TODATE(field_expression, input_date_format, output_date_format)

So if you input date is in the format DDMMYYYY then you need to swap those formats around

```
TODATE(LoadDate,'%d%m%Y','%d/%m/%Y')
```